# Copy a whole table from a SQL Server CE database to another

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I'm developing a C# application and I want to copy a whole table from a SQL Server CE database to another programmatically. I know I can use this command in SQL Server, but I'm not sure how to use two database connections in one query in C#.

```
Select * into DestinationDB.dbo.tableName from SourceDB.dbo.SourceTable
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: a quick internet search would yield many good answers...

Comment: Actually, I did that. none of the results explained how to implement that code in C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't do it the same way as in SQL Server because there's no single server that manages both databases.  Your app is the only thing that links the two databases so the the data has to go through your app.  You're trying to do it the wrong way and that's why you can't find a solution: you're looking for the wrong thing.

There are examples of this out there.  I know, because I've written more than one myself.  You simply need to use a data adapter to populate a `DataTable` from the first database and then a data adapter to save the contents of that `DataTable` to the second database.  If the data sources are the same type then you can even use just one data adapter because the `SelectCommand` and `InsertCommand` can have different connections.

```
using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT statement here", "source connection string here"))
using (var destinationConnection = new SqlConnection("destination connection string here"))
using (var insertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT statement here", destinationConnection))
{
    // Add parameters to insertCommand here.

    adapter.InsertCommand = insertCommand;

    // Leave the RowState of all DataRows as Added so they are ready to be inserted.
    adapter.AcceptChangesDuringFill = false;

    var table = new DataTable();

    // Retrieve data from source and save to destination.
    adapter.Fill(table);
    adapter.Update(table);
}
```

That example uses SqlClient but it works the same for any provider, including SqlServerCe.

Comment: Thanks, I guess it will work perfect. But does recognize the primary key column or should it I define it somewhere? cause I don't want the identity values to change through copy process.

Comment: If you insert to a table with an identity column then values will be generated for that column just as they always are.  There's a command in T-SQL to allow insertion of existing values in that column but I'm not sure whether it's supported in CE.  That's something that you can research for yourself.